# How can I send URL parameters to my server using $http.post with AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs

I have the following code:

```
$http.post('/api/City?cityId=' + $scope.config.cityId)
```

This works and sends the expected URL to the server.

Now I would like to add more to the URL to send additional information. Is there a way I can define the details such as cityId in an object and have this sent? Note that I did try:

```
$http.post('/api/City', {
             params: {
                 cityId: $scope.config.cityId
             }
})
```

This has the effect of sending a JSON object containing cityId to the server which is not what I want in this case as my server is expecting this:

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ActionName("City")]
    public HttpResponseMessage City(int cityId, int locId, testId)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The params object is a property of the third parameter to the $http.post function, not the second.

http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#post

You can also use the long version

```
$http({
  method: 'POST',
  url: '/api/City'
  params: {...}
});
```